# Setting variable from git output and using variable in command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

So in bash I can do the following:

```
SHORT_HASH=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
docker build --target build-image -t "build-image:$SHORT_HASH" .
docker build --target general-image -t "general-image:$SHORT_HASH" .
```

How would one do this simply in PowerShell?

Comment: Add `$` in front of `SHORT_HASH` and remove the grave accents from your git call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$` when assigning to the variable, and remove the `` ` `` backticks around the expression:

```
$SHORT_HASH = git rev-parse --short HEAD
docker build --target build-image -t "build-image:$SHORT_HASH" .
docker build --target general-image -t "general-image:$SHORT_HASH" .
```

Comment: You don't need to quote `-t`, fwiw

Comment: I don't think you have to quote anything, unless it begins with a hyphen and you have a variable without a colon in front of it..